# macOS: which font do I need to install for "Word Separator Middle Dot"

Tags: font, mojave, font-book

I have this option in my vimrc:

```
set listchars=tab:>-,trail:¬,extends:>,precedes:<,space:⸱
```

I use this char: https://unicode-table.com/en/2E31/

for space, word separator.  Though it does not show up, instead question mark appear [?]

Does anyone know which font do I need to setup for this?

Comment: The next page of that link shows it  displaying in times new roman and arial https://unicode-table.com/en/2E31/

Comment: (Go to full version )